# Why table_seq is generated though I not specify it

Tags: java, openjpa

I'm using OpenJPA 2.2.2 my persistence.xml is like follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>

    <class>package.User</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres" />
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="postgres" />
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="****" />

        <property name="openjpa.DynamicEnhancementAgent" value="true" />
        <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="supported" />

        <property name="openjpa.Log" value="SQL=TRACE" />
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryProperties" value="PrettyPrint=true, PrettyPrintLineLength=72, PrintParameters=true, MaxActive=10, MaxIdle=5, MinIdle=2, MaxWait=60000" />

        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

and User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;
    ...
```

despite that seq_table is created and sequence (native one) is not. How to fix it to use built-in sequence I'm using postgreSQL. Also I do not understand why each PK is +50 of previous one when using above.

Comment: Please do not set RuntimeUnenhancedClasses to supported. Also you'll be much happier in the long run if you read through the OpenJPA pages talking about enhancement.... the DynamicEnhancementAgent is nice to get going, but not something I'd keep in long term. http://openjpa.apache.org/entity-enhancement.html

Comment: @Rick
I've tried once. After a week going through unreadable documentation I gave up. It's too hard for me so I use this because it's WORK.

Comment: I 100% understand...just don't be upset when you encounter a bug due to using that feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also I do not understand why each PK is +50 of previous one when using above.

The reason that every PK is +50 from the previous is most likely because you're frequently? creating new EntityManagerFactories. Each time a new EMF is created, it will go back to the sequence table to get a new batch of 50 keys by default. Each time you throw away an EMF, any of the keys that aren't used will essentially be thrown away.

Comment: Sorry for late accept. You are right, whenever I change anything in servlet context got reload and sequence throws away unused values. Not happening in production environment, though.